# Excel VBA - Return selected element in slicer

Tags: vba, excel

I have a slicer called 'Slicer_HeaderTitle'. I simply need to be able to dim a variable in VBA with the value of the selected element. I'll only have one element selected at a time.

I've had a lot of problems with selecting and de-selecting elements from my slicer dynamically via VBA, since my pivot table is connected to an external data-source. I don't know if this is relevant for this exact example, but this table is connected to the same external data-source.

I used to have a single line of code, which could return this value, but all i could find now requires you loop through each element in the slicer and check if it's selected or not. I hope to avoid this, since I only have 1 selected element at a time.

[image]

```
' This is what I'm trying to achieve.
Dim sValue as String
sValue = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_HeaderTitle").VisibleSlicerItems.Value

msgbox(sValue)
'Returns: "Uge 14 - 2016 (3. Apr - 9. Apr)"
```

---

Current Status:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is what i did:

```
Public Function GetSelectedSlicerItems(SlicerName As String) As String
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim sI As SlicerItem

Set SL = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName).SlicerCacheLevels(1)
For Each sI In SL.SlicerItems
    If sI.Selected = True Then
         GetSelectedSlicerItems = (sI.Value)
    End If
Next
End Function


Dim sValue As String
sValue = GetSelectedSlicerItems("Slicer_HeaderTitle")
```

Thanks to Doktor OSwaldo for helping me a lot!

Comment: Just a note from the documentation as I kept getting errors - "The SlicerCacheLevels property applies only to slicers that filter OLAP data sources (SlicerCache.OLAP = True). Attempting to access this property from non-OLAP slicers will generate a run-time error."  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicercache.slicercachelevels

Comment: Does anyone know a workaround for non-OLAP data sources?

Answer (score 4):

Ok to find the error, we will take a step back, delete my function and try Looping through the items:

```
Dim sC As SlicerCache 
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel 
Dim sI As SlicerItem
Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Dates_Hie") 
Set SL = sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)
For Each sI In SL.SlicerItems    
  sC.VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(sI.Name) 
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have a small problem. I keep getting the msg "No items selected".

Comment: that's not really helpful, add a debug.print osi.Name after the For each and look if each element you have in the slicer is there, then check if the selected one has selected = true or not.

Comment: I've added a picture of my code and error at the bottom of the original post!

Comment: [Link](http://prntscr.com/ashww1)

I get error code on 'Set SL = sC.SlicerCacheLevels(2)', however if i change cachelevels to 1, then it outputs each of the elements in the slicer.

Comment: try it like it is now, is it working ? Sorry i have no Access to a slicer atm, so i have to guess a bit

Comment: ok i have to go now, i will look in this on monday, until then try with the 'Set SL = sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1) and test fot the .Selected Properity, maybe someone will help you better than I do in the mean time

Answer (score 2):

I would like to put in my two cents. The set of visible slicer items may be shrunk by both independent actions:

1. User selection of items in slicer A. To capture those items, use `.Selected` method.
2. Selection of items in slicer B which in consequence shrinks the list of slicer A items. To capture those items, use `.HasData` method.

Note that you may see only say two items of `Slicer_Products` (apples, bananas) because some other slicer `Slicer_Product_Type` has active filter on `fruits`. The method `sI.Selected` would still return the whole list of products apples, bananas, carrots...

If you want both limitations to be in place then make intersection of both sets. I have modified TobiasKnudsen code (excellent answer!) to return the list of items shrunk by both above limitations. `If sI.Selected = True And sI.HasData = True Then` is the key line in this code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestExample()
    Dim MyArr() As Variant
    MyArr = ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems("Slicer_A")
    'now variable MyArr keeps all items in an array
End Sub

Public Function ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems(MySlicerName As String) As Variant
    'This function returns an array of the limited set of items in Slicer A
    'Limitation is due to both:
    '(1) direct selection of items by user in slicer A
    '(2) selection of items in slicer B which in consequence limits the number of items in slicer A

    Dim ShortList() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0 'for iterate

    Dim sC As SlicerCache
    Dim sI As SlicerItem 'for iterate

    Set sC = ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(MySlicerName)
    For Each sI In sC.SlicerItems
        If sI.Selected = True And sI.HasData = True Then 'Here is the condition!!!
                'Debug.Print sI.Name
            ReDim Preserve ShortList(i)
            ShortList(i) = sI.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next sI
    ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems = ShortList
End Function
```

Comment: This is a little redundant: `ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook`.  Other than that, Nice work. +1

Comment: No, it is not redundant. I learned it the hard way. Sometimes you may have installed some addins working in the background which may change active workbook. If you use ThisWorkbook you are safe.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub Demo()
Dim i As Integer
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country")
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        If .SlicerItems(i).Selected Then
            Sheets("Pivot Sheet").Range("I" & i) = SlicerSelections & " " & .SlicerItems(i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End With
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to identify the selected element on a slicer.

The answer by TobiasKnudsen above did not work for me as I got an error stating the data source needed to be an OLAP source.

My data is an excel table and this is the code that worked:

```
Dim val as Boolean
val = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_MYSLICER").VisibleSlicerItems.Item("CS").HasData
```

In my case, the slicer had only 3 items so I repeated the line above with a different string in `item()`

So, where `val` was true, that was the item that was currently selected.